# how to check msbuid version list?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2022

Can anybody share the version list for msbuild, msbuild.corext, msbuild.Bridge.Corext?

If it's wrapped in VS, where can I get the latest supported version. They can be updated in corext.config.

Thanks

Comment: Check the document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022